# Best way to organize data in Elasticache Redis

Tags: database, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have two datasets i want to store in Redis, the records for each of them look like this:

1. customerId(String)(Key) , type(String), myData (Map)
2. salesPersonId(String)(Key), customerId(String), relationship(String), restriction(String)

Certain customerId might be salesPersonId in the second table. Think of it like a customer can also be a salesperson

I'm super new to Redis and i'm seeing so many different ways of storing this data, eg: Storing as 2 databases in the same cluster, storing them across different cluster etc.

I'm currently considering 2 databases in the same cluster approach...but not fully convinced.

I'm also confused as to what data structure to use store this record in redis, is it just simply a ->
key, parameter1 value, parameter2 value2, parameter3 value3 approach or is there a better way to organize this ?(This is the approach i'm considering currently)

I've been doing a lot of digging around and going down rabbit holes of redis, any guidance/ examples would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As both of the datatype may use the same keys in some cases, your choice is indeed between 2 databases on the same redis instance or separated redis instances. The answer to this question depends on the use, like:

1. Are there clients which are allowed to read/write to only one of the dbs?
   It will be easier manage access with two separate redis instances.
2. When reading from one db, how likely is is that you will read from the other db as well?
   If you are most likely to read from them both at each access, then dealing with one connection to redis server can be easier.

Regarding data type:
If you store the data as a concatenated string, you will have to parse fields from each entry at the client side upon every read. It would be more convenient to store each item in a small hash. For example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET <customer-id> type <type> data <customer-data>
(integer) 2
```

And later retrieve it with

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HGET <customer-id> data
"<customer-data>"
```

Read more about redis hash here [Redis hashes](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/hashes/)